# Is there a way to get "in-page analytics" through Google analytics API?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I do site which have to get some data from google analytics through google analytics API, and faced with problem getting in-page analytics. Namely - map of clicks with google settings on their in-page.

Is there a way to get "in-page analytics" through Google analytics API?
or I have to do it myself on the data, which I can get using Dimensions and Metrics? (I mean to put a map of clicks on my site in iframe...)

Sorry, for my bad English...